# How to execute scp locally using fabric

Tags: python, fabric, scp

I am using fabric right now to upload a large directory of files to ~100 different servers. These servers don't have rsync installed, so that's out of the question. Right now, I am using the upload_project method to accomplish this which is working well on the test servers I have, but I have heard that ftp (even if it's sftp) isn't allowed on some of these servers and that I might also need to limit the bandwidth of the transfer. To avoid these problems, I am trying to use scp, however, I am having some issues. I originally thought I could just go by the code in the rsync_project method and do something like `local("scp -r  %s %s" % (local_str, remote_str)`. However, scp still wants a password. So, I echoed the env.password to scp, which worked, but then it needed me to type yes to accept the key. I know I could just echo the password and echo yes to any key prompt, but I was wondering if there was some other way to accomplish this without all of the prompts. Also, sadly, the version of fabric on the server (which I cannot update) is a bit behind (1.6ish) and doesn't have the context-lib functionality that can handle prompts.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was some other way to accomplish this without all of the prompts

The answer is not exactly related to Fabric. In the case of your `scp` command, you should look into the [`StrictHostKeyChecking` option](https://serverfault.com/questions/330503/scp-without-known-hosts-check), to skip the known hosts key check. Example usage:

```
scp $src $dest -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

It sounds like you've addressed the issue with the password prompt; was there anything else you were trying to solve here?